# Solve the following equation. Check all proposed solutions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the following equation.  Check all proposed solutions.  Show all work in solving and checking, and state your final answer

[image]

my work

First let's add the fractions on the left.  To add any fraction, you must put them over a common denominator, in this case $(x+2)(x^2-4)$

Multiply out the numerator and denominator then combine like terms, 
but after doing all that I got

$-16=x^3+4x^2-17x $

and I can't get value for $x$

Comment: Did you forget to factorise $(x^2 - 4)$ ?

Comment: I already did (x-2)(x+2) but still stuck

Comment: Notice that $x=\pm 2$ cannot be solutions since they make the denominator zero on the left hand side. Therefore, we can divide by $x-2$ and get the below answer.

Answer (score 2):

Outline

You forgot to factorize $(x^2 - 4) = (x + 2)(x -2)$ from the denominator. Then the LCM becomes $(x^2 - 4)$ in which case the numerator gives

$5(x - 2) - 4 = (x-3)(x + 2)$, so you will get $(x^2-6x+8) = 0$ which is $(x- 4)(x-2) = 0$. Looking at the equation $\color{red}{x = 4}$ is the only solution.
This is because when you put $x = 2$, the original equation is undefined.